# What are some ways to handle bad files in Azure Datafactory Copy Activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

When using the default datafactory copy activity to load files from json blobs (source using modified timestamp) to sqldb table (destination). For the fault-tolerant settings, if the row is incompatible then it gets skipped, however if there is a bad file that is not a valid json format then the activity errors and retries instead of skipping the bad file.

What are some ways to identify/skip incompatible or corrupt files in ADF copy activity?

Thanks in advance

[failure log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvwXn.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Fault tolerance of copy activity in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-fault-tolerance#copying-tabular-data), the fault tolerance of copy activity only support **binary files** and **tabular data**.
Identify invalid json files is not supported yet.